# Django make dataframe available in view but read it just ONCE

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to accomplish the following. I've a simple `view`, something like the following

```py
def view(request):
    df = pd.read_csv('t.csv')
    """
    Some code to parse parameters from request
    """
    y = parse_some_parameters(request)


    """ 
    Do something with df.
    """
    if request.method=="POST":
        x = do_something(df, y)
    return(JsonResponse(x))
```

With the current implementation, every call to the `view` involves reading the file. I want to avoid this. I would like to read the `df` once when I start the server and make it available in the `view`. 
I tried reading the `df` in the `settings.py` file but its not visible within the `view`.
How would I accomplish this? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply set a variable outside of the view function, loading it if not set already?

```py
df = None

def view(request):
    global df
    if df is None:
        df = pd.read_csv('t.csv')

    """
    Some code to parse parameters from request
    """
    y = parse_some_parameters(request)


    """ 
    Do something with df.
    """
    if request.method=="POST":
        x = do_something(df, y)
    return(JsonResponse(x))
```